# Inner product is bounded above by product of $\infty$-norm and $1$-norm

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, vectors, normed-spaces

> Show that if $u,v \in \mathbb R^m$, then $|u\cdot v|\leq \|u\|_\infty\|v\|_1$.

By Cauchy-Schwarz, $$|u\cdot v|\leq \|u\|_2\|v\|_2$$ Note also that $\|u\|_1\leq \sqrt{m}\|u\|_2 \leq m\|u\|_\infty$, and $\|v\|_\infty \leq \|v\|_2 \leq \|v\|_1$, so we get

$$|u\cdot v|\leq \sqrt{m}\|u\|_\infty\|v\|_1$$

How to get rid of $\sqrt{m}$ to get the desired inequality?

Comment: How about using the definitions of the infinity norm and the $1$-norm?

Comment: Use plain triangle inequality on the inner product expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u=(u_1, \dots, u_m)$ and $v=(v_1, \dots, v_m)$. You have

$$ | u \cdot v | = \left| \sum_{k=1}^m u_k v_k \right| \leq  \sum_{k=1}^m |u_k v_k|  \leq \|u\|_{\infty}  \sum_{k=1}^m  |v_k| = \|u\|_{\infty} \|v\|_1  $$

(you can put $\|u\|_{\infty}$ out of the sum because all the $|u_k|$ are less than or equal to $\|u\|_{\infty}$).

Comment: First inequality is wrong.  Use $|\sum u_k v_k| \le \sum |u_kv_k|$ first.